# Dwarf Fortress "Goblet" Stockpile not working?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I created a Stockpile in my Dining room area that is literally just "Finished Goods--->Goblets" and thats it. However I never see wooden cups or anything put there, they are instead put in the barrels where my "DRINKS" stockpile is?

I can't think of a reason why this wouldn't work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It could be a lot of different things. When you start messing with custom stockpile settings, there are a lot of ways to get it wrong. My guess however is that you inadvertently turned off all materials in your goblet stockpile, so it's trying to allow goblets as long as they aren't made of anything in particular, which is not likely.

Here's how to make a stockpile just for goblets. You can <kbd>q</kbd>uery your existing stockpile and enter its <kbd>s</kbd>ettings. First, you want <kbd>e</kbd>nable Finished Goods and <kbd>d</kbd>isable everything else. However, go down to Additional Options and make sure you <kbd>a</kbd>llow all, or again, all materials will be forbidden. (These settings are kind of vestigial and left over from before the more detailed material settings were invented.) Next, go to Finished Goods. Start by <kbd>a</kbd>llowing everything to fix whatever nonsense might be in the settings already. In the second column, <kbd>f</kbd>orbid everything in the Type list. (It says "Forbid Finished Goods" but it only means forbidding all types of finished goods, not any of the other settings.) *Leave everything else in the second column alone.* It should all be enabled. Finally, go over to the third column and and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to turn on goblets specifically.

At this point your stockpile should allow only goblets, made of any material at all, whether plant/animal based or not, of any quality, with any decorations.